# Casting fraction number to decimal throws Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cast

I have a table called `AssignmentMarks` that stores Student's assignment marks for different subjects.
This table has a column called `Marks varchar(10)`  which stores the marks. The marks can be like `1`, `2`, and also it can be `+`, `-` or `-+` which represents each sign a specific marks.

*Note: `+` is `1` mark, `-` is `-1` and `-+` is `0.5`*

While getting a student marks from the table I am facing the `Arithmetic Overflow` error which I don't know what is the cause of this error.

The query is as follow:

```
SELECT SUM(
   CAST(
      CASE 
       WHEN a.Marks IS NULL OR a.Marks = '' THEN 0
       WHEN a.Marks = '+' THEN 1
       WHEN a.Marks = '-' THEN -1
       WHEN a.Marks = '-+' THEN 0.5
       ELSE a.Marks
      END AS DECIMAL(5,2)
   )
)
FROM AssignmentMarks AS a WHERE a.StudentID=10
AND a.SubjectID=1
```

After Executing the above query I get the following error.

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 7
>
> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Any idea what is the main cause of this error?

Sample Data:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/556a4/2)

Comment: What does this return? `select * from AssignmentMarks a where try_cast(a.Marks as decimal(5,2)) is null and a.Marks not in ('+','-+','-') and a.Marks is not null and a.Marks != ''`

Comment: @scsimon returns nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From error message,

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

My first place where I could change is :

```
 ELSE a.Marks
```

and change it to

```
ELSE try_convert(int, a.Marks)
```

or convert to decimal , if you want

**Later edit**:

In case expression you have a few THEN with different data types: int, numeric, varchar. Due to data type precedence, when combines different data types, the lower data type is converted to the type with higher precedence
See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) information about it.

you can see this , by this example:

```
SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
FROM
  (select 0 as col) as a  

SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
FROM
  (select 1 as col) as a

SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
FROM
  (select -1 as col ) as a

SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
FROM
  (select 0.5 as col) as a   

SELECT   SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Precision') AS 'Precision',  
         SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(col,'Scale') AS 'Scale'
FROM
  (select '-+' as col) as a 



Base Type   Precision   Scale
int         10          0
Base Type   Precision   Scale
int         10          0
Base Type   Precision   Scale
int         10           0
Base Type   Precision   Scale
numeric     1           1
Base Type   Precision   Scale
varchar     0           0
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, One thing that I didn't understand is that if I change the `0.5` to `10.5` or higher then it doesn't give me the error. Why?

Comment: in case expression `WHEN a.Marks = '-+' THEN 0.5` changing to `WHEN a.Marks = '-+' THEN 10.5`

Comment: so why casting 0.5 decimal gives error and casting 10.5 to decimal does not

Comment: the error it wasn't from casting 0.5 to decimal. It is related to Data type precedence , see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017